# Does luggage need to be rechecked if your connection is in another country?

Tags: transit, luggage, etihad, auh

My girlfriend is traveling from Beijing to New York City. However, she has a connection in Abu Dhabi International Airport.

Will she need to re-check/re-claim her baggage in Abu Dhabi or will it be routed all the way to NYC?

Comment: Usually, one booking means luggage goes all the way. In some countries, if you have a domestic connection after an international flight (when you cross the border and pass through customs), you have to collect it and check it again. I have seen it in China and Canada, other countries probably have a similar rule.

Comment: The airline is Etihad Airways.

Comment: @Vince The customs-at-entry part (for domestic connections) is universally true outside Europe. I am not aware of any exceptions.

Comment: My understanding is that if one has even an international transfer in the US one must recheck luggage, but I have no personal experience of this.  I know that one must clear passport control but I am not certain about customs.

Comment: @phoog Yes, US Customs must be cleared for int-int except in a very small number of cases (your bag gets a big red label with "International to International" or "ITI" printed on it, only available at MIA and DFW with participating airlines); and for through-flights with a stop in the US such as NZ 1/2 operating AKL-LHR via LAX.

Comment: @phoog However, the US is (almost) unique in this respect because it designs its airports without a dedicated international-only departure lounge.

Comment: @Calchas the [CBP Inspector's Field Manual](https://shusterman.com/pdf/cbpinspectorsfieldmanual.pdf), in section 22.10, actually describes a procedure where international transit lounge passengers do not need to clear immigration: "The transit passenger inspection (TPI) shall consist of a visual examination of ITI passengers.... This does not require an examination of each passenger and their travel documents. Questioning of ITI passengers and examination of travel documents shall be done selectively and on a random basis...."  So it seems that airport design is indeed the controlling factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are flying on Etihad Airways, your baggage will be checked all the way through.

You can even avail US pre-clearance which is available at Abu Dhabi to avoid delays when landing in NYC.

Answer (score 2):

If you bought the tickets together, then typically yes, the luggage will be transferred for you.  If you bought the tickets separately from two different airlines, then typically no.  If you are just changing planes within the same airline, always yes.

Comment: If you bought the tickets separately, you can sometimes still ask the check in staff to arrange for a baggage transfer. They can tell you if it's possible or if you need to go to a baggage transfer counter on the transit airport.

Comment: Apparently there is a thing called an "interlining agreement" between airlines.  I don't know how it works.

Comment: @pnuts -- the US is a special case.  Alone (afaik) among the nations, we have no exit controls:  you just walk out.  The downside of this is, there is no "airside" at the airport.  If you change planes at a US airport, you must go through passport control and demonstrate you have the legal right to enter the US (you can get a simpler, but not simple, transit visa).  Of necessity, you go through Customs, with your carry-on luggage.  It may be that your airline will give you your checked luggage so you can take it through too.  I just don't know.

Comment: @pnuts -- if you transfer from an international flight to a domestic one, you always (afaik) have to get your luggage and walk it through customs.  If it were interlined from international to domestic, it would never go through customs at all.